# Install Solr into Xampp

Tags: solr, tomcat7

with description.

> http://www.icuriousmedia.com/blog/how-to-install-apache-solr-on-windows-xp-1439.php

I tried to do it many times, but it still Fails

> HTTP Status 404 - /solr/admin
>
> type Status report
>
> message /solr/admin
>
> description The requested resource (/solr/admin) is not available.

I dont' understand why?

I use

- Xampp 1.7.4.
- Tomcat 7.0
- JDK 7

Answer (score 3):

That post is 2 years old. Maybe that's the reason why the author complains about lack of resources.
Now, there's plenty of those around.

E.g. this one: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall

The whole Solr installation procedure boils down to deploying war file to Tomcat or embedded Jetty.

Comment: And this wiki entry is always up to date : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Tomcat_on_Windows